# understanding paint.measureText

Tags: android

Need some help to understand paint object in android. I have a string object named myString. I load that with some content in a txt file which I have under assets.
In my code when I do myString.length() on that I get a vlue of 16708.

And when I use paint object as below to get the length, I get a value of 211050

```
myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
Paint paint = myTextView.getPaint();
float length = paint.measureText(myString, 0, myString.length());
```

I get a value of length as 211050.

Now I am trying to understand that what are these values here. 16708 is obviously the total length of my string in characters. And what is 211050 here? Is it the string width in pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the length on the screen your text will take in terms of pixels.

Edited:

Yes, [`paint.breakText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#breakText(char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float%5B%5D)) helps in breaking the string according to the max width provided in the parameter.

But one must also use [`setSubpixelText (true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint#setSubpixelText(boolean)) to account for the strings containing **i** or **l** (small **L**) or **w**, as breaktext somehow fails to determine the exact length of the broken string using `breakText()`.
Atleast I faced this problem, which I resolved using `setSubpixelText()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. So just to take it further, paint.breaktext returns the width(again in pixels) of the string to a specified lenght(in characters) as fed in the method's parameters?